# Checking out and compiling repository. What is the correct approach for starting the compilation process?

Tags: design, scripting, compilation

I am writing a Bash script that automatically updates a repository containing source code and then compiles it. I have been a bit stuck on the part about how to start the compilation itself, i.e. if I should `cat` all the files in the repository and look for the `main` (or equivalent) function and then compile that file. Or if I should let the user specify which file in the repository contains the `main` function (or possibly a `make`file) in the config file. This option requires more work and insight from the user, but I fear that the first option might cause long delays by unnecessary scanning all the files in the repository. What would be the best approach for solving this problem?

Comment: This depends a lot on what kind of files are in the repository. For a C projects `./configure && make && make install` is a form of a de-facto standard. For Python `python setup.py install` is the same. The platform you are using also contributes. Windows users would tend to use a visual studio project rather than the command line to compile native code.

Comment: I presume you mean "*checks out* a repository and then compiles it"?

Comment: Checks out (if it does not already exist) or updates it with the newest revision if it does.